# ASP.NET Core minimal API - Failure to infer one or more parameters

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) on Microsoft Documentation to create a minimal API and I came across this error on visual studio :

```
System.InvalidOperationException : 'Failure to infer one or more parameters.
```

Here the code that I'm using:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.

 app.UseHttpsRedirection();

 app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello world !");

 // CREATE NEW ITEM /INVENTORY/ITEM
 app.MapPost("/inventory/item", async (Product product, ProductsDb db) =>
 {
 db.Products.Add(product);
 await db.SaveChangesAsync();

  return Results.Created($"/inventory/{product.Barcode}", product);
  });


  // DELETE ITEM /ITEM
 app.MapDelete("/item/{bc}", async (int bc, ProductsDb db) =>
 {
if (await db.Products.FindAsync(bc) is Product product)
{
    db.Products.Remove(product);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Results.Ok(product);
 }

return Results.NotFound();
});


// UPDATE ITEM /INVENTORY/item/{barecode}
app.MapPut("/inventory/item/{bc}", async (int bc, Product inputProduct, ProductsDb db) 
=>
{
var product = await db.Products.FindAsync(bc);

if (product is null) return Results.NotFound();

product.Name = inputProduct.Name;
product.Category = inputProduct.Category;
product.Price = inputProduct.Price;
product.Discount = inputProduct.Discount;
product.Quantity = inputProduct.Quantity;

await db.SaveChangesAsync();

return Results.NoContent();
});


// GET AL ITEMS  /INVENTORY/ITEMS
app.MapGet("/inventory/item", async (ProductsDb db) =>
await db.Products.ToListAsync());


// GET AL ITEMS  /INVENTORY/ITEMS/query?category={category}
app.MapGet("/inventory/items/query?category={category}", async (int bc, ProductsDb db) 
=>
await db.Products.FindAsync(bc)
    is Product product
        ? Results.Ok(product)
        : Results.NotFound());

 // GET AL ITEMS SORTED IN DESCENDING /INVENTORY/ITEM/SORT
app.MapGet("/inventory/item/sort", async (ProductsDb db) =>
await db.Products.OrderBy(p =>p.Price).ToListAsync());
app.Run();

class Product
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public int Price { get; set; }
public int Discount { get; set; }
public int Quantity { get; set; }
public int Barcode { get; set; }
 }

class ProductsDb : DbContext
{
public ProductsDb(DbContextOptions<ProductsDb> options)
    : base(options) { }

public DbSet<Product> Products => Set<Product>();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to provide some API end point that will get or post some products in a database (Entity framework code first)

I'm using EntityFramework.InMemory like the tutorial but I have no idea why it generates this error, am I doing something wrong ? thank you !

Answer (score 3):

First, you need to add the context after the builder.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add these two lines
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProductsDb>(opt => opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("ProductsList"));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
```

Next, you have to correct this method as follows:

```
// GET AL ITEMS /inventory/items/category/{barecode}
app.MapGet("/inventory/items/category/{bc}", async (int bc, ProductsDb db) 
// ...
```

Finally, you have to set a nullable or default value in your entity strings in order to avoid a nullable reference error.

```
public string? Name { get; set; }
public string? Category { get; set; }

// OR
// public string Name { get; set; } = "default name";
// public string Category { get; set; } = "default category";
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message was [updated](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35405) to better communicate the issue with dependency resolution. Now it also contains a table with the delegate's parameters and their inferred sources:

```bash
System.InvalidOperationException
Failure to infer one or more parameters.
Below is the list of parameters that we found: 

Parameter           | Source                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
event               | Body (Inferred)
handler             | UNKNOWN
```

To resolve the issue, we can manually add Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC `From*` attribute to the problematic parameter, like:

```
app.MapPost(route, (Event<TPayload> @event, [FromServices]IMessageHandler<TPayload?> handler) =>
 handler.Handle(@event.GetPayload()));
```